# Can non-Jews pray to change their "mazal"?

Tags: tefilla, gentiles

I don't have the sources for this, but I know that there is a principle that Jews can daven (pray) to change our mazal (sort of like luck, but probably not a great translation).  I know that there is a gemara that says that Jews have no mazal, but I believe that more recent commentaries have clarified it to be that we do, but it can be changed by tefillah (prayer).

As far as I understand it, non-Jews can also pray to Hashem and He listens, so is it not possible for a non-Jew who has sufficient merit and prays to change their mazal?  If so, what does it mean that Jews can change our mazal but non-Jews can't?

Comment: aside from prayer which non Jews should engage in, wouldn’t non Jews who become noahides or even converts be proof that even actions they do can change their mazal?

Comment: @JewishContext depends on how you understand what a convert is. One perspective is that it is someone that was born with a Jewish neshama but covered over and they have the choice to reveal it. I don't think becoming a concert or becoming a Noahide is nogea to mazal but more so to do with the level of bechiras chafshis each person is given

Comment: Good background reading from Rabbeinu Bachya - https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Devarim.31.14.1?ven=Torah_Commentary_by_Rabbi_Bachya_ben_Asher,_trans._Eliyahu_Munk,_1998.&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: Why do you assume non-Jews can influence mazal?

Comment: @Dov Thanks for the link, although it doesn't mention any difference between Jews and non-Jews.  I'm not absolutely assuming that non-Jews can change mazal, just that it seems hard to believe that they can't, as it is hard to believe that their tefillos wouldn't be accepted for not being Jewish, and we can't say that Hashem isn't capable of overriding mazal, so it is hard to see a reason why they shouldn't be able to?

Comment: The link provides a good background from a Jewish perspective and help give context to you question - though I am yet to see any sources that demonstrate that non-Jews have any impact on mazal

Comment: Jews can change mazal not just with prayer, but good or bad deeds. The Gemara gives examples of giving charity. AFAIK that doesn't work for non-Jews.

Comment: @N.T. That seems hard to understand - why shouldn't they be rewarded for tzedakah too?

Comment: They are rewarded, but I don't think it can totally change their mazal as with Jews.